# React-Native QR Code Scanner REST API Binding

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, api, rest

I have a mobile qr code scanner application. I want to match the information in the scanned QR code from the REST API (matching in json) and print it on the screen. Can I do these operations? I would like to get information from people who are knowledgeable about this subject, through which stages I can do the subject. (You can also post a link to an article or article related to the subject.). I may have expressed myself wrong as I am not very knowledgeable about the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this amazing library and onRead function you can set some state and render that data on screen using that state.

[react-native-qrcode-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-scanner)

Comment: There is a library that I am currently using. What exactly does onRead do?

Comment: Well a function is passed to onRead prop and when a QR Code is scanned then this function is triggered. So basically you can pass your custom function to this prop which sets the QR Data that needs to be rendered on screen. Please refer to this link for documentation of this library

https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner